# Solving the 8 queens

Tags: java, breadth-first-search

What I am trying to do is solving the 8 queen problem to produce 1 solution. I am trying to do this using BFS. Below is what I have done so far.  I think all my functions/methods are all correct apart from the final method() which I can't get to work. If I compile and run the following code, I get a NullPointerException. Wondering how I can overcome this problem and get it to work.

```
public class Queens 
{
//Number of rows or columns

public int[][] board; // creating a two dimentional array

public int Queen = 1;
//Indicate an empty square
public boolean Conflict(int row, int col) 
{
    int[ ][ ]board = new int[8][8];
    int row1;
    int col1;
    boolean flg = false;
    row1 = row;
    col1 = col;
    // check right
    while(row1<8)
    {
        if(board[row1][col1]==1)
        {
            row1++;

        }
    }

//check left
    while(row1>=0)
    {
        if(board[row1][col1]==1)
        {
            row1--;
        }
    }
// check down
    while(col1<8)
    {
        if(board[row1][col1]==1)
        {
           col1++;
        }
    }

// check up 
    while(col1>1)
    {

        if (board[row1][col1]==1)
        {
            col1--;
        }

    }
//dia-down-right
while(row1<8 && col1<8){
    if(board[row1][col1]==1)
    {
        row1++;
        col1++;
    }
}

//dia-down-left
while(row1>=0 && col1<8){
    if(board[row1][col1]==1)
    row1--;
    col1++;
}   
//dia-up-left
while(row1>=0 && col1>=0){
    if(board[row1][col1]==1)
    row1--;
    col1--;
}

//dia-up-right
while(row1<8 && col1>=0){
    if(board[row1][col1]==1)
    row1++;
    col1--;
}       
    return flg;



}

public void disp()
{
int i,j;
for(i=0;i<8;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<8;j++)
    {
        System.out.println(board[j][i]);
    }
                //System.out.println(board[j][i]);
}
}

public void init()
{
int i,j;
for(i=0;i<8;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<8;j++)
    {
        board[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
}

public void placeQueen(int x,int y)
{
board[x][y]= Queen;
Queen++;
}

public void method()
{


int x,y;
int initx=0;
int inity=0;

Queen=0;
init();

placeQueen(initx,inity);
y=0;
while(y<8)
{
    x=0;
    while(x<8)
    {
        if(!Conflict(x,y))
        {
            placeQueen(x,y);
            x++;
        }
    }
    y++;
}
if(Queen<8){
    if(initx+1<8)
    {
        initx++;
        disp();
    }
    else
    {
        initx=0;
        if(inity+1<8)
        {
            inity++;
        }
        else{
            disp();
            }
    }


}

}   
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
Queens Main = new Queens();
Main.method();

}
}
```

Comment: Some observations: In your method `Conflict(int row, int col)`: After each verification (left, right, down, etc) you must reset the values of `row1`, `col1` , etc. to it's original values (i.g. `row1 = row` and `col1 = col`.

Comment: Why the Up verification only check up to 2 (`while(col1>1)`)? Shouldn't be `while(col1 >= 0)`?

Comment: Thanks I've done that but I still can't sort out my final method, concept has really confused me. I think my comments are wrong for a couple of them. I believe I have covered all directions.

Comment: This is much more easy using DFS. It need to be BFS?

Comment: Ok I see that problem, ive sorted it however I am still getting this nullpointer error. Yes I have do it in BFS, Ive already done it in DFS using backtracking but now I need to do BFS

Comment: Maybe a silly question...Where is your queue?

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement a queue for this problem. Will I use it in the method()?

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize the board on line 5, otherwise when called in init board:

```
board[i][j] = 0;
```

board[i][j] is null

```
public class Queens
{
//Number of rows or columns

    public int[][] board = new int[8][8]; // creating a two dimentional array

    public int Queen = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you that works but I still can't solve why my method() doesn't work

Comment: I don't see how you're setting the flg boolean for a conflict. You don't seem to update it anyway in the code you provided.

Comment: Also when I ran the code you provided above it showed it was stuck in the while loop in the conflict method. 
You seem to initialize the board to all 0s and then in the conflict method you have a while loop that terminates when row1 is greater than 8 but row1 only increments when a spot on the board is 1.
Since everything in board is zero it can't reach the increment line to eventually leave the loop.